# Single click to show results using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using this code;

```
if ($forum['type'] != 'c' && !$forum['linkto'] && $forum['posts'])
{
    $forum['collapsed_image'] = '<div class="expcolimage"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="forum_name" fid="'.$fid.'" title="Double click here to see latest threads of this section."><img src="images/collapse_collapsed.gif" id="ann_'.$forum['fid'].'_img" class="expander" alt="[-]" title="[-]" /></a></div>';
}
else
{
    $forum['collapsed_image'] = '';
}
```

And here is my jquery code;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="forum_name"]').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fid = $(this).attr("fid");
        $.ajax(
        {
            type : "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url : "misc.php?action=forum_threads&fid="+fid,
            cache: false,
            success : function(response)
            {
                $("#forum_threads_"+fid).stop().slideToggle("fast").html(response);
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Now what it does is when you DOUBLE click on the link above then the jquery code runs and show the results. Instead of this I want to make it so I can only click ONCE to run the jquery code to show the results. How to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using the `e.preventDefault()` for?

Comment: @ Arun: the code is fine, I asked how to make it so only one click could make the code runs instead two clicks??

Comment: @user2854563 because you don't need it. If you remove the href attribute, you don't get redirected as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mjsppovq/3/,

The code runs on single click, make sure that you haven't any other js code interfering with id starting with forum_name

```
<div class="expcolimage"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="forum_name_123" fid="123" title="Double click here to see latest threads of this section."><img src="images/collapse_collapsed.gif" id="ann_123_img" class="expander" alt="[-]" title="[-]" /></a>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="forum_name"]').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fid = $(this).attr("fid");
    console.log(fid);
    $.ajax(
    {
        type : "post",
        dataType: "html",
        url : "misc.php?action=forum_threads&fid="+fid,
        cache: false,
        success : function(response)
        {
            $("#forum_threads_"+fid).stop().slideToggle("fast").html(response);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

use inspect to view console.log output

Comment: Thanks idwaker but its running on two clicks, not one

Answer (score -2):

```
$forum['collapsed_image'] = '<div class="expcolimage"><a  id="forum_name" fid="'.$fid.'" title="Double click here to see latest threads of this section."><img src="images/collapse_collapsed.gif" id="ann_'.$forum['fid'].'_img" class="expander" alt="[-]" title="[-]" /></a></div>';
```

remove `href="javascript:void(0);" from anchor tag`

Comment: clean the cache of browser and run and then let me know

Comment: for just checking remove e.preventDefault();

Comment: tried clearing the cache also removing `e.preventDefault();` nothing works

Comment: you are missing something else . not in this code . and stop voting down

Comment: bind all these events in outer div .or write something in between anchor tag . I think your a tag is too tiny

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[id^="forum_name"]').click(function(event){
```